# laravel 5.3: ErrorException in UrlGenerator.php line 314: Route [] not defined

Tags: php, laravel-5

Here my routes code in web.php

```
Route::get('/login', array("as" => "login-admin", 'uses' => 'Auth\LoginController@login'));
```

Controller method:

```
public function login()
{
    return view('admin-access.login_form');

}
```

Error message show:

> ErrorException in UrlGenerator.php line 314: Route [] not defined.
>   (View:
>   /var/www/html/lara_project/cust-todo/resources/views/admin-access/login_form.blade.php).

How i can solve that problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should take a look at [Laravel Routing](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/routing). It looks you got a problem in your Route.

Try this

```
Route::get('login',['as' => 'login-admin', 'uses' => 'Auth\LoginController@login']);
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to pass in array instead you can directly write in square brackets.

```
Route::get('login',['as' => 'login-admin', 'uses' => 'Auth\LoginController@login']);
```