# Route not defined. (laravel)

Tags: php, laravel

I am getting below **error :**

> ErrorException Route [iocallreport/export-file/] not defined. (View:
>   E:\xampp\htdocs\ec2\html\pbxreport\resources\views\cms\reports\iocallreport.blade.php)

code in **view :**

```
 <a href="{{ route('iocallreport/export-file/',['type'=>'xls']) }}">Download Excel xls</a> |

 <a href="{{ route('iocallreport/export-file/',['type'=>'xlsx']) }}">Download Excel xlsx</a> |

 <a href="{{ route('iocallreport/export-file/',['type'=>'csv']) }}">Download CSV</a>
```

and below is my *route* in **web.php**

```
Route::get('/iocallreport/export-file/{type}', 'Cms\ReportsController@exportFile');
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [laravel 5.3: ErrorException in UrlGenerator.php line 314: Route \[\] not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41399861/laravel-5-3-errorexception-in-urlgenerator-php-line-314-route-not-defined)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this

```
<a href="{{ url('iocallreport/export-file/',['type'=>'xls']) }}">Download Excel xls</a> |

<a href="{{ url('iocallreport/export-file/',['type'=>'xlsx']) }}">Download Excel   xlsx</a> |

<a href="{{ url('iocallreport/export-file/',['type'=>'csv']) }}">Download CSV</a>
```

I guess `route()` helper only works for `named routes`. So your code can not find route with name `iocallreport/export-file`

OR

If you want to use `route()` helper then try this.

```
Route::get('/iocallreport/export-file/{type}', 'Cms\ReportsController@exportFile')->name('iocallreport');
```

and use it here

```
<a href="{{ route('iocallreport',['type'=>'xls'])   }}">Download Excel xls</a> |

<a href="{{ route('iocallreport',['type'=>'xlsx']) }}">Download Excel xlsx</a> |

<a href="{{ route('iocallreport',['type'=>'csv']) }}">Download CSV</a>
```

You can give any suitable name to your route.

Answer (score 2):

`route` function takes **route name** as first argument. So, you have to name your route:

```
Route::get('/iocallreport/export-file/{type}', 'Cms\ReportsController@exportFile')->name('export_file_route');
```

And then use this name in `route`:

```
<a href="{{ route('export_file_route', ['type'=>'xls']) }}">Download Excel xls</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please add name for route and modify helper route() with this name:

```
Route::get('/iocallreport/export-file/{type}', 'Cms\ReportsController@exportFile')->name('export');

<a href="{{ route('export', ['type'=>'xls']) }}">Download Excel xls</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You must give a name for route:

```
Route::get(
    '/iocallreport/export-file/{type}',
    'Cms\ReportsController@exportFile'
)->name('export-file');
```

After, use route name in blade:

```
<a href="{{ route('export-file', ['type'=>'xls']) }}">Download Excel xls</a>
```

See: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/helpers#method-route