# Laravel Route Link - Error Route not Defined

Tags: php, laravel, routes

In my web.php containing my routes, I have the following Route:

```
Route::get('/profile', 'Profile\ProfileController@index');
```

Which links to my Profile Controller 
I am linking to this controller with

```
Route::get('/profile', 'Profile\ProfileController@index');
```

However, when I navigate to the page with this route set, I get this error

```
    ErrorException (E_ERROR)
Route [profile] not defined. (View: D:\MAMP\htdocs\milestoneexp\resources\views\layouts\app.blade.php) (View: D:\MAMP\htdocs\milestoneexp\resources\views\layouts\app.blade.php)
```

However, the following code works fine with navigation when I switch from route to URL

```
<a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ url('profile') }}">{{ __('Profile') }}</a>
```

Why does URL work but not route? And how can I make my route work?

Laravel version 5.8.35

Comment: that isn't the line causing the error ... somewhere there is a `route('profile')` call

Comment: route() function is used only to call the routes that has a name associated with the route. In your route declaration, you haven't specified a name for it, that's why the route() function doesn't work. You have do add a "->name('profile')" to your route declaration in web.php to make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively you can also do it this way:

```
Route::get('profile', [
    'as' => 'profile',
    'uses' => 'Profile\ProfileController@index',
]);
```

Answer (score 1):

The route has to be named, so the correct code in web.php for the route is

```
Route::get('/profile', 'Profile\ProfileController@index')->name('profile');
```

Source: [Route not defined. (laravel)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/53954936/route-not-defined-laravel)